# Where does git log get the author name in a rails app

Tags: git

I am using a git on a rails app I am working on and I am intrigued where `git log` retrieves the author name and email from. Thanks.

Comment: Check `~/.gitconfig`. It is global for all repos. Also git stores repo-specific credencials somewhere in `.git/config` for each repo.

Comment: This is the answer but how do you mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: It's a hint. Not an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it in `~/.gitconfig`. Thanks to @madhead

Answer (score 2):

When you set up git, it asks you for your name and email address.

The values you enter are stored in every commit you make.